# Breadth First Search or Depth First Search?

Tags: python, algorithm, graph

I am implementing a huge directed graph consisting of 100,000+ nodes. I am just beginning python so I only know of these two search algorithms. Which one would be more efficient if I wanted to find the shortest distance between any two nodes? Are there any other methods I'm not aware of that would be even better?

Thank you for your time

Comment: Use [Dijsktra Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm). It is BFS and used for internet packet routing (OSPF)

Comment: do you know about [dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming)? Knowing this concept will greatly help understanding the other algorithms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are indeed several other alternatives to BFS and DFS.

One that is quite adequate to computing shortest path is: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm

Dijsktra's Algorithm is basically an adaptation of a BFS algorithm, and it's much more efficient than searching the entire graph, if your graph is weighted.

Like a @ThomasH said, Djikstra is only relevant if you have a weighted graph, if the weight of every edge is the same, it basically defaults back to BFS.

If the choice is between BFS and DFS, then BFS is more adequate to finding shortest paths, because you explore the immediate vicinity of a node completely before moving on to nodes that are at a greater distance.

This means that if there's a path of size 3, it'll be explored before the algorithm moves on to exploring nodes at distance 4, for instance.

With DFS, you don't have such a guarantee, since you explore nodes in depth, you can find a longer path that just happened to be explored earlier, and you'll need to explore the entire graph to make sure that that is the shortest path.

As to why you're getting downvotes, most SO questions should show a little effort has been put into finding a solution, for instance, there are several related questions on the pros and cons of DFS versus BFS.

Next time try to make sure that you've searched a bit, and then ask questions about any specific doubts that you have.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but can you also tell me why I'm getting downvotes. My accounts keep getting blocked because I keep getting downvoted. I don't see anything wrong with my question to be honest...

Comment: Dijsktra is not relevant is there are no weights on edges.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the following two algorithms:

1. [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) - Single source shortest path
2. [Floyd-Warshall algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm) - All pairs shortest path

Comment: you should have put more text. Floyd indeed is a good fit for the op, the graph being weighted or not.

Answer (score 0):

If there are no weights for the edges on the graph, a simple Breadth-first search where you access nodes in the graph iteratively and check if any of the new nodes equals the destination-node can be done. If the edges have weights, DJikstra's algorithm and Bellman-Ford algoriths are things which you should be looking at, depending on your expected time and space complexities that you are looking at.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to find the shortest path you should use BFS and not DFS because BFS explores the closest nodes first so when you reach your goal you know for sure that you used the shortest path and you can stop searching. Whereas DFS explores one branch at a time so when you reach your goal you can't be sure that there is not another path via another branch that is shorter.

So you should use BFS.

If your graph have different weights on its edges, then you should use Dijkstra's algorithm which is an adaptation of BFS for weighted graphs, but don't use it if you don't have weights.

Some people may recommend you to use Floyd-Warshall algorithm but it is a very bad idea for a graph this large.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I think ill go with the BFS, the Dijsktra's Algorithm seems too hard for me to implement